Streamlit crashing when using ydata_profiling
I am using Streamlit to visualize my ydata_profiling report.
However when I am selecting a work_order to generate a profile report it keeps on crashing without any error message.
Attached screenshot:

I have used the same code in jupyter notebook and it is working fine. Please see reference:

The code is as follows:
Analytics Section
if choice == ' Analytics':
    st.subheader('Analytics')
    
    # Fetch all unique work orders from MongoDB
    work_orders = collection.distinct('Work_Order')
    if work_orders:
        # Create a multi-select dropdown for work orders
        selected_work_orders = st.multiselect('Select Work Orders:', work_orders)
        if selected_work_orders:
            # Fetch data for the selected work orders
            records = list(collection.find({"Work_Order": {"$in": selected_work_orders}}))
            if records:
                # Convert the list of MongoDB records to a DataFrame
                df = pd.DataFrame(records)
                # Drop the MongoDB internal fields if it's not needed
                if '_id' in df.columns:
                    df = df.drop(columns=['_id'])
                    df = df.drop(columns=['Object_Detection_Visual'])

                # Generate a profiling report using ydata-profiling
                profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Work Orders Data Profile", minimal=True)

                # Display the profiling report in Streamlit
                st_profile_report(profile)
            else:
                st.write("No data found for the selected work orders.")
        else:
            st.write("Please select one or more work orders to analyze.")
    else:
        st.write("No work orders available.")

Also I am fetching the data from MongoDB and I have checked mongodb is connected.
The dataframe is as follows:

Versions:
os: Windows
python: 3.11
streamlit: 1.35.0
streamlit-pandas-profiling: 0.1.3
ydata-profiling: 4.9.0


I have replicated the situation and verified that your code works.
There seem to be no errors in streamlit or your code. I think this might be related to windows.

My env:
python: 3.11.9
streamlit: 1.35.0
streamlit-pandas-profiling: 0.1.3
ydata-profiling: 4.9.0
os: macos v12.7.4

